# Slide_down animation to show a view

Tags: android, animation

I have a layout with 2 child. One is at the half top, and the other is below. The one at the top starts with the visibility `GONE` state so the second child gets at the half top.

What I do is. When I touch an element from the second child, this child makes a slide_down animation to it's original place, and the first child is shown at the half top.

The problem comes now. The second child has a `layout_marginTop="20dp"` property so at the begining, when it is on the half top, it has this margin with the top. And when the animation starts, it moves to the top of the screen and goes to it's original position. This is, the animation doesn't start from its current position, it starts from the top of the screen. this is my slide_down animation.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <translate android:fromYDelta="-100%" android:toYDelta="0%" android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

I know this has something to do with the `fromYDelta="-100%"`, but is there any way to start the animation from the place where the child is at that moment?

Comment: To start the animation from where the view is you have to use `fromYDelta="0%"

Comment: @Pedro Oliveira I think maybe my explanation is a bit confusing, but it's real place is at 0%, that's why it finishes there. It's starting place isn't it's real place, because there is a view that is not showing, so this view is place upwards it's real place

Comment: `the animation doesn't start from its current position, it starts from the top of the screen` That's because of `android:fromYDelta="-100%"`. I think you have to reformulate your question because that's not just a "bit" confusing.

Comment: @Pedro Oliveira I know, but due to language limitations is a bit dificult to do it. I have now setted android:fromYDelta="-70%" and it fits the desired behavior, but I don't know if in different screen size/densities it will match too

Comment: My suggestion is to animate the view using animate() instead of an animation. That way you can execute a translation on Y using values from the other views too, making it work on all screen sizes (just have to do a bit of math)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use TranslateAnimation code in your Java file instead xml.
let us consider A and B are your Views, and 
A is at Half Top with visibility gone and B is at bottom Half..
when you click on any child in B..it need to slide down from top making A visible...

```
A.setVisibility(View.GONE); //initially
TranslateAnimation slide_down=new TranslateAnimation(B.getScaleX(),B.getScaleX(),B.getScaleY()-20,B.getScaleY());
slide_down.setDuration(500);
slide_down.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            A.setVisibility(View.Visible);
            }
        });

B.startAnimation(slide_down); //start Animation when child view is clicked
```